# How to make an atomic batch update containing multiple APKs

Tags: android

Is it possible to batch APK installs in order to make an atomic call that would update multiple apps at once ?

The use case is that I need to upgrade apps (using their .apk) having dependencies. Thus, I need to be able for a batch to whether update all apps or update none.

Android provides a rollback for single apk update in case it fails, does it provide such mechanism for multiple apps ?

I saw a [`setMultiPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams.html#setMultiPackage()) method on `PackageInstaller`'s `SessionPackage` but it is starting at API level 29 and I need to support API level 28 and it is not well documented so I'm not sure it fills my needs.

---

Given the fact that this will be running on a pure AOSP, how costly would it be to implement such a mechanism at system level ?